# Resetting my form after submitting

Tags: php

I want to set the fields to the beginning values when the submit button is pressed. below is my html form:

```
<form method="post" name="offerte" id="offerte" action="stuur_offerte.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="message">
    <div class="left-form">
        <p>Ik ben een:</p>
        <input type="radio" name="soort" value="particulier" checked> Particulier
        <input type="radio" name="soort" value="bedrijf"> Bedrijf
        <br>
        <p>Type gebouw:</p>
        <select name="gebouw">
            <option value="woonhuis">Woonhuis</option>
            <option value="kantoor">Kantoor</option>
            <option value="winkel">Winkel</option>
            <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
            <option value="bedrijfshal">Bedrijfshal</option>
            <option value="anders">Anders</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <p>Inhoud ruimte(n) (LxBxH):</p>
        Ruimte 1
        <input type="text" class="ruimte" maxlength="3" name="ruimte1"> M3
        <br> Ruimte 2
        <input type="text" class="ruimte" maxlength="3" name="ruimte2"> M3
        <br> Ruimte 3
        <input class="ruimte" type="text" maxlength="3" name="ruimte3"> M3
        <br> Ruimte 4
        <input type="text" class="ruimte" maxlength="3" name="ruimte4"> M3
        <br>
        <p>Locatie buitenunit:</p>
        <select name="buitenunit">
            <option value="aan de muur">Aan de muur</option>
            <option value="op het dak">Op het dak</option>
            <option value="op de grond">Op de grond</option>
            <option value="anders">Anders</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <p>Lengte aircoleiding:</p>
        <select name="leidinglengte">
            <option value="1 tot 5 meter">1 t/m 5</option>
            <option value="5 tot 10 meter">5 t/m 10</option>
            <option value="10 tot 15 meter">10 t/m 15</option>
            <option value="15 tot 20 meter">15 t/m 20</option>
            <option value="meer dan 20 meter">meer dan 20</option>
        </select> Meter
        <br>
        <p>Leidingen moeten naar buiten door een:</p>
        <select name="leidingdoorvoer">
            <option value="stenen muur">Stenen</option>
            <option value="betonnen muur">Betonnen</option>
            <option value="houten muur">Houten</option>
            <option value="anders">Anders</option>
        </select> Muur
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="right-form">
        <p>* Voornaam:</p>
        <input type="text" class="gegevens" name="voornaam">
        <br>
        <p>* Achternaam:</p>
        <input type="text" class="gegevens" name="achternaam">
        <br>
        <p>* Woonplaats:</p>
        <input type="text" class="gegevens" name="woonplaats">
        <br>
        <p>Telefoonnummer:</p>
        <input type="text" class="gegevens" name="telefoonnummer">
        <br>
        <p>* Email adres:</p>
        <input type="mail" class="gegevens" name="email">
        <br>
        <p>Extra informatie:</p>
        <textarea name="extratext" class="gegevens" cols="30" rows="5" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Aanvraag verzenden" class="submit-button" name="submit">
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" value="reset" class="reset-button" name="reset">
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe name="message" style="border-style: none; width: 45%; height: 200px;"></iframe>
```

And here is my php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "info@aircovoorinhuis.nl";
    $email_subject = "offerteaanvraag";

    function died($error) {
        echo $error . "";
        die();
    }

    $soort = $_POST['soort'];
    $gebouw = $_POST['gebouw'];
    $ruimte1 = $_POST['ruimte1'];
    $ruimte2 = $_POST['ruimte2'];
    $ruimte3 = $_POST['ruimte3'];
    $ruimte4 = $_POST['ruimte4'];
    $buitenunit = $_POST['buitenunit'];
    $leidinglengte = $_POST['leidinglengte'];
    $leidingdoorvoer = $_POST['leidingdoorvoer'];
    $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
    $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
    $woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
    $telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
    $afzender = $_POST['email'];
    $bericht = $_POST['extratext'];

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $afzender)) {
        $error_message.= '<h4 style="color:#f00">U heeft een ongeldig email-adres ingevuld</h4>';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $voornaam)) {
        $error_message.= '<h4 style="color:#f00">U heeft geen voornaam ingevuld</h4>';
    }

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $achternaam)) {
        $error_message.= '<h4 style="color:#f00">U heeft geen achternaam ingevuld</h4>';
    }

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $woonplaats)) {
        $error_message.= '<h4 style="color:#f00">U heeft geen woonplaats ingevuld</h4>';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "U heeft een offerte aanvraag ontvangen vanaf uw website.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array(
            "content-type",
            "bcc:",
            "to:",
            "cc:",
            "href"
        );
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message.= "Deze email is afkomstig van:\n\n";
    $email_message.= "Voornaam: " . clean_string($voornaam) . "\n";
    $email_message.= "Achternaam: " . clean_string($achternaam) . "\n";
    $email_message.= "Email adres: " . clean_string($afzender) . "\n\n";
    $email_message.= "$voornaam $achternaam is een $soort en doet een aavraag voor zijn/haar $gebouw in $woonplaats.\n";
    $email_message.= "Ruimte 1= $ruimte1 M3 \n";
    $email_message.= "Ruimte 2= $ruimte2 M3 \n";
    $email_message.= "Ruimte 3= $ruimte3 M3 \n";
    $email_message.= "Ruimte 4= $ruimte4 M3 \n";
    $email_message.= "De buitenunit kan worden geplaatst: $buitenunit en de leidinglengte tot de binnenunit(s) is; $leidinglengte.\n";
    $email_message.= "De leidingen moeten naar buiten worden geboord door een $leidingdoorvoer.\n";
    $email_message.= "Extra bericht: " . clean_string($bericht) . "\n";
    $headers = 'From: ' . $afzender . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $afzender . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
<h2>Uw bericht is verzonden</h2>

<?php
}
?>
```

i have tried many things, but nothing seems to work. if there are any other things that look weird, please feel free to tell me :)

Comment: What have you tried so far to reset the form?

Comment: Use javascript for this

Comment: Alternatively,  you can set the input values to null when mail is sent via php

Answer (score 0):

After mail sent to you just redirect to your form page by using header() function in php it will automatically get reset or refresh

```
header("Location:your_form_page_url");
```

Comment: how do i put this in my php, at what line?

Comment: you can put this code after mail has been sent i.e.  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  header("Location:your_form_page_url");

Comment: it opens the new page in my <iframe> section on the page. i use the iframe for the error messages

Comment: <iframe name="message" style="border-style: none; width: 45%; height: 200px;"></iframe>